# How to remove Windows 10 Bing / Copilot recommendation from search

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, bing

For quite some time now I have this annoying Recommended section pop up in my search (when clicking the search bar), suggesting me to try out "the new Bing" with "Your AI-powered copilot":

[image: Part of the search showing a recommended section suggesting trying out "the new Bing" with "Your AI-powered copilot"]

I can close this thing all I want, it will return within the next 5 boots and take up space that I'd rather see used with my Recent items because I start those quite frequently.

There is another variant of this as well that tries to ram Edge down my throat and takes up the same space.

How can I permanently remove these ads from my search?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/how-do-i-remove-hi-im-bing-your-ai-powered-copilot/8af7c291-3133-4337-8762-84d268c7ec9e

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/how-to-disable-bing-chat-on-microsoft-edge

Comment: Try setting TurnOffWindowsCopilot to 1

Comment: @ChanganAuto Those articles seem to talk about removing the Bing feature from Edge unless I am missing something and not about removing Bing ads from the Windows start menu.

Comment: @Ramhound Where would I set that?

Comment: Registry of course

Comment: Due to the non-answer that was submitted, I protected this question, since this no doubt will be a popular solution.

Comment: How you turn start menu recommendation is also well documented.  How you disable the Copilot preview, would involve the TurnOffWindowsCopilot key in the registry, and turning off the start menu recommendations would be a different key.

Comment: [Turn Off Suggested Start Menu ads in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-suggested-apps-start-menu-windows-10)

Comment: I researched the full path for the TurnOffWindowsCopilot key and found that it supports a group policy that is only available on Windows 11 according to [this Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/manage-windows-copilot). As for the last linked article, I had that setting turned off already and the Bing recommendation still showed up :/

Comment: I also just realized an embarassing mistake; it's technically not the start menu (shown on clicking the windows icon) but the search (shown when clicking the search bar); I had those confused. I updated the question accordingly but even with the correction I could not find any information online. Fwiw, I have all settings turned off that allow Windows Search to provide me with anything but Files an Folders, or so I thought.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 - You want to disable Search Recommendations, which I linked to a few comments ago

Comment: @Ramhound As mentioned in a previous comment, that setting has been turned off on both windows computers I am facing the issue on even before I wrote the question. The recommentation of Bing still shows up. There are no context menus either; I can remove the thing once by clicking the X but after a while it just shows up again.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 - This means the correct setting hasn't been disabled. However, I see no mention of that fact, in the question body.